# Android: AppCompatImageView custom style

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to **AppCompatImageView** through whole application by default.

```
<AppCompatImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" //I should write this for all AppCompatImageView
    ...
</AppCompatImageView>
```

Here's my AppTheme codes and I'm sure there will be options to set default style values for **AppCompatImageView**.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Please let me know how I can solve this.

Comment: why not try custom ImageView in Whole app

Comment: I thought giving style is much easier.

Comment: wont work below API 17

Comment: That's fine for me.

Comment: add this to your style `<item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>`

Comment: I wanted only for ImageView(AppCompatImageView).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152124/discussion-between-alexander-ignacz-and-abhishek-singh).